# Use mouse to get information about the underlying object in PyQt

Tags: qt, pyqt

I am working with a preexisting Python Qt desktop application. I don't understand where some graphical elements come from. I would like to be able to obtain information about the object that created e.g. a widget or button by hovering or clicking my mouse. I want to be able to go from the graphics displayed to me by the application to the underlying object or class. Anything like a class name or a reference to the object would be useful. Is there a function to do that in PyQt?

I tried googling this, but my results are completely overwhelmed by discussions of how to connect mouse callbacks to your widget, but my problem is trying to find a widget that I see, but don't know how to programmatically access.

Comment: [QApplication.widgetAt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#widgetAt).

Comment: "Graphical elements" is a quite vague description. While most elements of a GUI in Qt are widgets (so, the `widgetAt()` suggestion above from ekhumoro is the first thing to look for), your question is too broad. For what we know, that "preexisting" application could use graphical elements that are actually custom drawn, either in a special widget that explicitly draws those elements, or using complex aspects such as [model based views](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html) or the [graphics view framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).

Comment: Thank you, both your comments were very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from qtpy.QtWidgets import QApplication
from qtpy.QtGui import QCursor

app = QApplication.instance()
widget = app.widgetAt(QCursor.pos())
```

This will work for widgets, but may not work for custom drawn elements.